# How to uninstall OAuth2 OR fix it

Tags: drush

i'm new in Drupal.

I tried on my site to mount the OAuth2 world but I can't get to the top. The website shows an error that is

> Error: Interface 'League\OAuth2\Server\Repositories\AccessTokenRepositoryInterface' not found in include() (line 13 of modules/simple_oauth/src/Repositories/AccessTokenRepository.php).

same applies if I try to manually uninstall the module via ssh with **drush pm-uninstall simple_oauth oauth2_server** it is impossible:

> In Connection.php line 896:
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
> 'site_drupal.oauth2_token' doesn't exist: SELECT "base_table"."id"
> AS "id", "base_table"."id" AS "base_table_id" FROM
> {oauth2_token} "base_table"
> LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0; Array
> (
> )
>
> In StatementWrapper.php line 116:
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
> 'site_drupal.oauth2_token' doesn't exist

Basically: the site (or the admin section to uninstall the module) cannot be accessed unless this module presents this kind of error, and via ssh I can't figure out how to remove it.

I thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: How did you install the module? Did you not use composer? It should have retrieved the library for you when you installed it. I'm guessing maybe you did it manually?

Comment: You can add `metatag: 0` to `core.extensions.yml`.

Comment: @Jaypan ok, this has greatly reduced the error block, i added also webprofiler: 0 and this reduced more the error block, but there are still a few lines left: https://postimg.cc/dhFP2tbB. I think it is about "simple_oauth: 0" that i removed for solve the first "..Interface 'OAuth2\..". We returned to the beginning. :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

1. Run `drush cex` to export your configuration to the config directory.
2. Find the core.extensions.yml file in the configuration directory. Edit it, and remove the line that says: `oauth2_server: 0`
3. Run `drush cim`  to import your configuration. It should disable that module.